# Very confused with formatted Strings (Java)?

Tags: java, string, text, format, string-formatting

I trying to learn how to write formatted strings in java for console apps. but, no one really explained this subject very well so it gets a bit messy.

I need to know where to start, i can't learn it from java doc (The doc explains this topic really  terribly).

So, i surfed a lot in Wikipedia values like:

Template Languages,
scanf blala,
Data models.

I just can't understand even what this subject is?, why do we need it? and just why...

and what "fomat" / "formatted" means? design?

By the way, printf and scanf are string formats?

Comment: "*I trying to learn how to write formatted strings in java*", "*and what "fomat" / "formatted" means?*" - so you want to learn something, but you don't know what it is. Why? Do you have a specific problem that, you believe, can be solved with formatted Strings?

Comment: I know it allows me to design text (i think), but there are a lot of terms I just don't understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, "*allows me to design text*" seems like quite a broad statement. Can you be more specific? Do you have an example?

Comment: @lurker yea i tried, everyone explains only part of the subject but not the whole.

Comment: Only part of the subject? There's not much to explain when it comes to string formatting. So it sounds like you have an expectation or requirement you haven't clearly described. I'm not sure how searching for "Template Languages" or "Data Models" on Wikipedia would help.

Comment: @Fureeish yea, like I want to do, for example, that string like this

"| " + num + " |"

That the text will not increase as the num increases.

like when your make a meun in console game and the menu contains some value that changing dynamically everytime so you don't want that the menu will be increased. i can explain more clearly if it's not (because i know it's not).

Comment: See [Java Formatted Strings](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) just as one of numerous example explanations from a Google search. In your specific text example, `System.out.printf("| %4d |", num)` would print `" |" + num + " |"` and always use 4 spaces of width to hold `num`. You can set 4 to whatever you like.

Comment: That sounds like you want a fixed-width representations. Do you find [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) lacking? I strongly advise you to learn how to effectively read and extract information form documentations. It will be an invaluable skill in your programming future.

Comment: @lurker yes this width thing. thanks it's helpful.

Comment: @Fureeish yea you right. thx!

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me figure out what I needed.